# docker connect cockroachDB failed

Tags: docker, cockroachdb, cadence-workflow, uber-cadence

I'm using docker to start cadence server, but I can't connect to my cockroachDB, the following error occurs.

[image]

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

In your connection string, could you try adding `?sslmode=require` or `?sslmode=verify-ca/full`. Clusters on Cockroach Cloud require a secure connection in order to connect to the DB.

Our recommendation is to use `verify-full` or `verify-ca` which protect against MITM attacks and enforce verifying that the server certificate is signed by known certificate authority.

We've got some docs on additional connection parameters here! https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/connection-parameters.html#additional-connection-parameters

And some more specific docs on SSL Modes with Cockroach Cloud here:
https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/cockroachcloud/authentication.html#ssl-mode-settings